# c++, minify dynamic array by delete [] x[i]

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I have a 2D array with size 4 (4 rows). To make the array size 2 (2 rows), can I use following? (for our hw assignment details are not specified and the code should be suitable with common c++ standarts)

I am removing second half of the array.

```
const int newSize = flightsArraySize/2;
for(int i = newSize-1; i < flightsArraySize-1; i++)
   delete [] flights[i];
```

Or do I have to recreate flights array with size 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that you have created a 2D array using new like this:

```
int **arr = new int*[rows];
for(int i=0; i<rows; ++i)
    arr[i] = new int[cols];
```

Then to resize it you'd have to do something like:

```
int newRows = rows/2;

// Create a new array for the right number of rows.
int **newArr = new int*[newRows];

// Copy the rows we're keeping across.
for(int i=0; i<newRows; ++i)
    newArr[i] = arr[i];

// Delete the rows we no longer need.
for(int i=newRows; i<rows; ++i)
    delete[] arr[i];

// Delete the old array.
delete[] arr;

// Replace the old array and row count with the new ones.
arr = newArr;
rows = newRows;
```

But seriously, this is all so much easier if you just use vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(rows);
for(int i=0; i<rows; ++i)
    v[i].resize(cols);
v.resize(v.size()/2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I have to use array. It's a pain in the.. for a big project

Answer (score 0):

Well, it deallocates the memory on which pointed the second half of pointers. But the poiters themselves will stay, the array of pointers will not be shortened.

#### EDIT

Oh, sorry. It seems as a mistake. If you have code like this:

```
int **ptr = new int*[4];

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    ptr[i] = new int[4];
}
```

Then when you type

```
delete[] ptr[3];
```

It will delete the whole array, so you can create new like this:

```
ptr[3] = new int[any_number];
```

Is this what you mean? Sorry, I read too fast...

Comment: Then I should recreate flights array?

Comment: I have specified the answer, it seems I read too fast :-) basically, if you have array of pointers and every this pointer points to an array of values, then you can delete[] the pointer and the array completely disappears. Than you can 'new' it again.